# Parsing the Image URL with Filepicker.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, filepicker.io

I am trying to post the Image url and what is coming out is something like so=

https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/GEghdsg4Shy7aY0xY6ywc

And what I want is

https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/asdf8dsf7asdfasdf.png

For this ruins the Fancy Box code I use since it is checking if it is an image in that plugin.

My code is as follows-

```
$(function(){
 filepicker.setKey('myKey');
   $("#newImage").on('click',function(){
         filepicker.pick({mimetypes: ['image/*'],},function(FPFile) {
       var imgU = FPFile.url;
       var text=$('#text_editor_textarea');
    text.val(text.val()+'[img]'+imgU+'[/img]');
   });
 });
});
```

I tried other methods of FPFile.url and honestly i can't seem to find the correct way to parse out the image url and not the hosting location url.

Comment: None of the images work.

Comment: Not suppose to as I made the urls up ;)

Comment: I was just using them as examples to show how the URL is being parsed. And Fancy Box within the plugin has this line of code = (gif||png||jpg||jpeg||bmp) meaning its testing the url if its an actual image. So I need to figure out how to parse the URL to be something like the above with .png or whatever file type at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filepicker will ignore things after a + so you can add anything you want after a + in the url.

E.G. Both will resolve properly.

https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/GEghdsg4Shy7aY0xY6ywc

https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/GEghdsg4Shy7aY0xY6ywc+whateveryouwant.png

Comment: Just as a note, neither of the links above will resolve because again, those were made up links by the original poster.

Comment: AS this doesn't help so much, maybe you could explain what to place in the JS not the url...

`FPfile.url+FPFile.filename+FBFile.extension` ?